# C++ get picture from HTTP response

Tags: c++, image, sockets, http, header

I'm trying to download picture from website. The problem is that even tho I get all the content from HTTP response body, file won't open. I've been trying to solve this but I can't find the real problem. One thing I did notice is that picture downloaded using chromium displays different characters than picture downloaded from my code using command: 
**$ cat picture.png | less**

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//with this function I remove HTTP header info, so I only get content.
char *removeHTTPHeader(char *buffer) {
    char *t = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
    t = t + 4;
    return t;
}

void getPicture(const int &socketfd, const int &bSize) {
    std::ofstream file("picture.png",
            std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);

    char buffer[bSize];
    ssize_t bReceived;

    bReceived = recv(socketfd, buffer, bSize, 0);
    char *t = removeHTTPHeader(buffer);
    file.write(t, strlen(t));
    memset(buffer, 0, bSize);

    while ((bReceived = recv(socketfd, buffer, bSize, 0)) > 0) {
        file.write(buffer, bReceived);
        memset(buffer, 0, bSize);
    }

    file.close();
}

int main() {

    int status;
    addrinfo host_info;
    addrinfo *host_info_list;

    memset(&host_info, 0, sizeof(host_info));

    host_info.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    host_info.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    host_info.ai_protocol = 0;

    status = getaddrinfo("www.pngimg.com", "80", &host_info, &host_info_list);
    if (status != 0) {
        cout << "getaddrinfo error" << endl;
    }

    int socketfd;
    socketfd = socket(host_info_list->ai_family, host_info_list->ai_socktype,
            host_info_list->ai_protocol);

    addrinfo *rp;
    for (rp = host_info_list; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {

        socketfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);

        if (socketfd == -1) {
            cout << "socket error" << endl;
        }

        if (connect(socketfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1) {
            break;
        }
        close(socketfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not connect!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(host_info_list);

    const char *msg =
            "GET /upload/water_PNG3290.png HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: www.pngimg.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

    status = send(socketfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    if (status == -1) {
        cout << "error sending" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    getPicture(socketfd, 1024);
    close(socketfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is picture from using cat command:
[terminal above is picture from my code, below is picture from chromium "save as"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqDf0.png)

Comment: You can't use `strlen` on binary data.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. But I guess that's not the real problem.

Comment: Constructing a `std::string` from a `char*` will stop at the first 0 in the data as well.  You'd most likely want to subtract the number of bytes in the header from `bReceived` and then write the rest of the buffer to the file.

Comment: Thank you! I did as you told me. I changed removeHTTPHeader back to char* and did count on body size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I didn't know that in C style string you can't do strlen on binary data. That's why I had to add counter in function removeHTTPHeader. Below are function getPicture and removeHTTPHeader that I've changed.

```
char *removeHTTPHeader(char *buffer, int &bodySize) {
    char *t = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
    t = t + 4;

    for (auto it = buffer; it != t; ++it) {
        ++bodySize;
    }

    return t;
}

void getPicture(const int &socketfd, const int &bSize) {
    std::ofstream file("picture.png",
            std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);

    char buffer[bSize];
    ssize_t bReceived;

    bReceived = recv(socketfd, buffer, bSize, 0);
    int bodySize = 0;

    char *t = removeHTTPHeader(buffer, bodySize);
    bodySize = bReceived - bodySize;

    file.write(t, bodySize);
    memset(buffer, 0, bSize);

    while ((bReceived = recv(socketfd, buffer, bSize, 0)) > 0) {
        file.write(buffer, bReceived);
        memset(buffer, 0, bSize);
    }

    file.close();
}
```